# Item disappearing from cart when logging in when Mage_Sales_Order_Quote is overridden not to

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

Magento version is **1.6.2.0**. I have overridden `Mage_Sales_Order_Quote` in `app/code/local` to not just increase quantity if the `desiger` option is set. I have a design system that a person can click a link in the product view and they are taken to the designer that we made, then the product is added pragmatically to cart.

I changed the `getItemByProduct` to the following:

```
public function getItemByProduct($product)
{
    $_options = unserialize($product->getCustomOption('info_buyRequest')->getValue());
    $_designs = $_options['options']['designer'];
    foreach ($this->getAllItems() as $item) {
        if ($item->representProduct($product)) {
            $_itemOptions = unserialize($item->getProduct()->getCustomOption('info_buyRequest')->getValue());
            if (!empty($_designs) && !empty($_itemOptions['options']['designer'])) { // consider detecting if this was a re-design
                return false;
            } else {
                return $item;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now, the functionality works as intended, except for the fact that if I am logged out and have items in the cart, when I log in the items are merged once again like default functionality used to be and not my override. Where else would I look to remove this? I have the "Save Cart to Database" setting enabled to make carts persistent, in case that is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Create an Observer that listens to the event `sales_quote_merge_before` and clears the customer's saved cart:

Create an Observer class at `/app/code/local/{namespace}/{yourmodule}/Model/Observer.php`

```
<?php
class <namespace>_<modulename>_Model_Observer
{
  public function preventMerge(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
  {
    // Clear the customer's cart
  }
```

Then, add the following to your /app/code/local/{namespace}/{yourmodule}/etc/config.xml file for the module:

```
<config>
  ...
  <frontend>
    ...
    <events>
      <sales_quote_merge_before>
        <observers>
          <sales_quote_merge_before_event>
            <class>{modulename}/observer</class>
            <method>preventMerge</method>
          </sales_quote_merge_before_event>
        </observers>
      </sales_quote_merge_before>
    </events>
    ...
  </frontend>
  ...
</config>
```